# Acer crystal eye webcam stopped working

Tags: 12.04, webcam, acer, cheese

I'm not sure what went wrong, or what I did. But one day it suddenly wasn't working.

In Cheese Webcam Booth it shows a black screen. The little camera light next to the webcam isn't switched on.

In Edit -> Preferences-> Webcam in the Device dropdown it has "Acer Crystal Eye Webcam(/dev/video0)" but the dropdown is disabled and greyed out.

Im on Ubuntu 12.04.2, on an Acer Travelmate 5320

```
matthew@matthew-Travelmate5320:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:0105 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 12d1:140c Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 04d9:0499 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Optical Mouse


matthew@matthew-Travelmate5320:/var/log$ grep webcam dmesg*
dmesg:[   27.234010] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Acer Crystal Eye webcam (5986:0105)
dmesg:[   27.295492] input: Acer Crystal Eye webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input5
dmesg.0:[   27.132769] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Acer Crystal Eye webcam (5986:0105)
dmesg.0:[   27.243793] input: Acer Crystal Eye webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input5
```

The webcam is working fine when I boot windows.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: check group membership.  you should be a member of the video group (or not if you don't want your user to be able to use the webcam)

Comment: @CallmeV thanks for the response. Installed gnome-system-tools. Found the video group and clicked properties. Saw my user but checkbox was unchecked. Checked it. Saved. Rebooted. The problem still persists though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This never got resolved for several months. What I did notice is that after Ubuntu updates it would suddenly work after the first reboot and thereafter stop working for several weeks until another Ubuntu update. Eventually an update resolved the issue for good.